# ¿Cómo hacer un progress bar con tres porcentajes en angular 15?

Tags: angular

Estoy intentando hacer un progres bar, como este del ejemplo:

[image: ejemplo]

Este progress está formado por el porcetaje del verde, naranja y rojo.

En este momento, la parte del html que tengo es este:

`

```
                                <div class="progress-bar" style="    border-radius: 3px;
                                height: 6px;
                                margin: 0;
                                overflow: hidden;
                                padding: 0;
                                width: 40px;
                                box-sizing: border-box;
                                background-color: transparent;
                                box-shadow: none;
                                display: block;">
                                    <div class="flex items-end ml-2 w-1 h-4 bg-green-100 rounded overflow-hidden"
                                    *ngIf="selectedBehaviorTypesResultsCountByCountry[country.key].passedPercent">
                                    <div class="flex w-full h-full bg-green-400"></div>
                                </div>
                                


                       
                                </div>`
```

El resultado que tengo es este:

[image: resultado]

Comment: y el problema es????

Comment: @gbianchi el problema es que no sé como se hace en angular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la directiva ngStyle para establecer la anchura de cada sección de la barra de progreso. El código HTML sería similar a esto:

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar bg-success" role="progressbar" [ngStyle]="{ 'width': percent1 + '%' }"></div>
  <div class="progress-bar bg-warning" role="progressbar" [ngStyle]="{ 'width': percent2 + '%' }"></div>
  <div class="progress-bar bg-danger" role="progressbar" [ngStyle]="{ 'width': percent3 + '%' }"></div>
</div>
```

En este ejemplo, percent1, percent2 y percent3 son variables que contienen el porcentaje de progreso de cada sección.

Además, necesitarás definir las clases CSS progress y progress-bar para dar estilo a la barra de progreso y sus secciones:

```
.progress {
  height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.progress-bar {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #007bff;
  transition: width 0.6s ease;
}
```

Este es solo un ejemplo básico, pero puedes personalizar el estilo de la barra de progreso y sus secciones según tus necesidades. Espero que esto te haya sido útil.

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Me ha sido de gran ayuda